# Powershell script analyze MFA

Tags: powershell, multi-factor-authentication

I have this PowerShell comand that I don't quite understand:

```
Get-MsolUser -all | select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,@{N="MFA Status"; E={ if( $_.StrongAuthenticationMethods.IsDefault -eq $true) {($_.StrongAuthenticationMethods | Where IsDefault -eq $True).MethodType} else { "Disabled"}}} | FT -AutoSize
```

Can someone please explain what `@{N="MFA Status"; E=` stands for?

Answer (score 1):

This is related to calculated properties - here is some good examples:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ff730948(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#using-calculated-properties

N stands for Name as in what the property will be called in the list produced - can be whatever you want it to be

E for Expression where you do the voodoo to calculate this new value